# Circle CI only passes when "Rebuild without Cache"

Tags: react-native, babeljs, circleci

Each time the project needs to be built the Circle CI fails. However, when it gets rebuilt as "Rebuild without Cache" it passes.

It gets really annoying to have to rerun it each time manually.

```
> escrow@0.0.1 bundle /home/ubuntu/escrow
> node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output iOS/main.jsbundle

/home/ubuntu/escrow/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:193
          throw new ReferenceError(messages.get("pluginUnknown", plugin, loc, i, dirname));
          ^

ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-es2015-arrow-functions" specified in "/home/ubuntu/escrow/.babelrc" at 2, attempted to resolve relative to "/home/ubuntu/escrow"
    at /home/ubuntu/escrow/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:193:17
    at Array.map (native)
    at Function.normalisePlugins (/home/ubuntu/escrow/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:173:20)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/home/ubuntu/escrow/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:271:36)
    at OptionManager.addConfig (/home/ubuntu/escrow/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:221:10)
    at OptionManager.findConfigs (/home/ubuntu/escrow/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:364:16)
    at OptionManager.init (/home/ubuntu/escrow/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:412:12)
    at compile (/home/ubuntu/escrow/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:87:26)
    at loader (/home/ubuntu/escrow/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:130:14)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/ubuntu/escrow/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:140:7)
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react-native",
  ],
  "plugins": [
    //Needed for redux.
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-class-properties", //this needs to be at top /shrug

    // es2015 preset (except transform-es2015-typeof-symbol which caused problem)
    "transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
    "transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions",
    "transform-es2015-block-scoping",
    "transform-es2015-classes",
    "transform-es2015-computed-properties",
    "transform-es2015-constants",
    "transform-es2015-destructuring",
    "transform-es2015-for-of",
    "transform-es2015-function-name",
    "transform-es2015-literals",
    "transform-es2015-object-super",
    "transform-es2015-parameters",
    "transform-es2015-shorthand-properties",
    "transform-es2015-spread",
    "transform-es2015-sticky-regex",
    "transform-es2015-template-literals",
    "transform-es2015-unicode-regex",

    // stage-1 preset
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    "transform-exponentiation-operator",
    "syntax-trailing-function-commas",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-class-constructor-call",
    "transform-decorators",
    "transform-export-extensions",
  ]
}
```